# How to configure Kotlin in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

How can I configure Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA? I am using it for Android development with Android SDK, I can code with Java in it to develop Android apps, but when I choose Kotlin, I get many errors. I think my problem is I didn't configure Kotlin in it. So how can I do it?

[Here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2jGN.png)

I tried but couldn't find an option to configure Kotlin.

The error shown in the images

I try to find the option to configure Kotlin in IntelliJ, but haven't found it.

The errors I am getting are shown in the image, check it.

Comment: Why you don't use Android Studio instead of Intellij ?

Comment: If you are developing for Android, what is stopping you from using Android Studio (the official IDE) https://developer.android.com/studio?

Answer (score -1):

try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MAJ</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Configure Kotlin in Project

In my case i go this :

[image]